# How Can I Hide / Show One of Listed Buttons in Table With Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
$( "#test1" ).click(function() {
    $(this).next("#test2").slideToggle( "slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="test1" id="test1" value="TEST1" /> 
      <br/>
      <input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" id="test2" value="TEST2" /><br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="submit" name="test1" id="test1" value="TEST1" /><br/>
      <input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" id="test2" value="TEST2" /><br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Hi, I wanted to show or hide test2 button(in a selected row) after clicking test1 button in a table. But there is a problem that there are several buttons 
having the same id. Is that possible to show or hide selected button? Can you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Multiple IDs in HTML is invalid.

Comment: You can use same classes on them not id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assign a class as mentioned in the comments, and use `siblings('.someclassname')` to choose the sibling sections. Going through your code, as follows:

```js
$(".buttontype1").click(function() {

  $(this).siblings(".buttontype2").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="test1" id="test1" value="TEST1" class="buttontype1" /><br/>
        <input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" id="test2" value="TEST2" class="buttontype2" /><br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="test1" id="test1" value="TEST1" class="buttontype1" /><br/>
        <input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" id="test2" value="TEST2" class="buttontype2" /><br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID's should never be repeated on a page, they should always be unique. If you need to repeat a reference/element then use it as a class.

So when someone clicks on a button (or anything) that has a class you can reference it as `$(this)`

**Example:**

```
<td> <-- this is .parent()
    <input type="submit" name="test1" class="test1" value="TEST1" /> <-- This is $(this) when clicked
    <input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" class="test2" value="TEST2" /> <-- this is .find('.test2')
</td>

$(document).on('click','.test1', function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.test2').show(); <-- or hide()
})
```

No need to `<br>` between your first and second button since the second is already hidden.

To break it down

`$(this)` = `<input type="submit" name="test1" class="test1" value="TEST1" />`

`.parent()` = Your first `<td>` on top

`.find('.test2')` = `<input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" class="test2" value="TEST2" />`

`.show() or .hide()` = Show or hide element

Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use same class names on different elements not the same id

```js
$(".test1").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings(".test2").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete.
    $(".test2").show()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="test1" class="test1" value="TEST1" /><br/>
        <input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" class="test2" value="TEST2" /><br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" name="test1" class="test1" value="TEST1" /><br/>
        <input style="display: none;" type="submit" name="test2" class="test2" value="TEST2" /><br/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```